# Did God give Moses visions of History and the Tabernacle on Mount Sinai?

Tags: exegesis, genesis, exodus, moses, inspiration

After Moses spent forty days and nights on the mountain, he gave the people the requirements God had told him to say to the Israelites:

All Scripture is quoted from the King James translation unless otherwise noted.

> Exodus 19:3  And Moses went up unto God, and the LORD called unto him out of the mountain, saying, Thus shalt thou say to the house of Jacob, and tell the children of Israel;

In the chapters between 19 and 25 are the laws God gave Moses, but in chapter 25,God in giving Moses instructions on building the Tabernacle said:

> Exodus 25:8 and 9  And let them make me a sanctuary; that I may dwell among them. According to ***all that I shew thee***, after the pattern of the tabernacle, and the pattern of all the instruments thereof, even so shall ye make it.

according to that Scripture God showed Moses some visions, and also;

> Exodus 25:40  And look that thou make them after their ***pattern, which was shewed thee in the mount***.

If I am reading the Scriptures correctly God not only told Moses what to tell the Israelites to do, but also gave him visions of exactly how the Tabernacle and its furnishings should be made.

Did God also give Moses visions of History which he then recorded in Genesis?

Comment: Related: [How did Moses write the events which happened ~2000 years before him?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/22847/how-did-moses-write-the-events-which-happened-2000-years-before-him)

Comment: @Mawia that question though related does not cover visions.

Comment: @Bye The selected answer in that question quoted by Mawia cites both *historical narrative and special revelation*. Does vision not come under the purview of special revelations? If not, what about dreams and dark speech? Word of knowledge? Or was the time on Mt. Sinai somehow not special...

Answer (score -2):

Most definitely. The passage makes it clear that the earthly sanctuary was modeled after another Sanctuary, the True Sanctuary made by the LORD Himself. This is what was shown to Moses in vision.

> Now this is the main point of the things we are saying: We have such a
>   High Priest, who is seated at the right hand of the throne of the
>   Majesty in the heavens, a Minister of **the sanctuary and of the true
>   tabernacle which the Lord erected, and not man**.
>
> Hebrews 8:1,2
>
> For if He were on earth, He would not be a priest, since there are
>   priests who offer the gifts according to the law; 5 **who serve the copy
>   and shadow of the heavenly things, as Moses was divinely instructed
>   when he was about to make the tabernacle. For He said, “See that you
>   make all things according to the pattern shown you on the
>   mountain.”**[a] 6 But now He has obtained a more excellent ministry,
>   inasmuch as He is also Mediator of a better covenant, which was
>   established on better promises.
>
> Hebrews 8:4,6

Divine inspiration does not work in the way that God dictates word for word, as it is known that different authors had different writing styles. Nevertheless, they were all inspired by the Holy Spirit. Because Moses did not live in that time, a vision must have been shown to him in order for him to be able to write the Genesis account in such detail. Some also think that Moses was the author of the Book of Job.

Comment: I would also like to comment that this is why we should study the earthly sanctuary and its rituals, because it gives us insight into the heavenly sanctuary and the work of Christ before, during, and after the cross.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, please explain why as it will help improve the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the down vote I will change it as soon as I can, should be an up vote

Comment: @Bye I did notice it didn't answer your question completely and added a bit more so that it would be more complete. :)

Comment: Without some additional textual support, using what metaphoric language from the new testament as proof of something literal in the old testament seems like a pretty week argument.

Comment: The tabernacle, the priestly laws etc are all a type of the heavenly things, some are also a type of the Messiah's sacrifice. Such is in line with the Lord's Prayer; *Let Your will be done on earth as it is in heaven*. The verses cited and explanation given does not give me an ounce of the historical narrative of Creation. I find it both speculative and narrow. Hence, the superlatives *most definitely* should not be used. I think *there is no direct answer* is better. But hey.

Comment: @Flimzy what part exactly in the text is metaphoric and how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: What do the words 'The LORD erected' mean? Also, it says that the LORD to Moses to build a tabernacle from the one that the LORD had SHOWN him. I don't understand the down-votes when this is pretty clear. At least explain why you don't find this answer useful, and are therefore down-voting. This way I can make the answer better.

Comment: @jlaverde: "what part exactly in the text is metaphoric" Practically all of it. "right hand of the throne" -- metaphor. Or do you believe God sits on a literal throne? "true tabernacle" -- metaphor. "Tabernacle" here probably means [the church](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/hebrews/8-2.htm). It obvoiusly does not mean a physical box or place of worship. Do you need me to continue?

Comment: @Flimzy All of these definitely are literal. Where in the Bible does it say otherwise? Can someone not sit on the right side of a throne? I certainly believe so. Also, the tabernacle being the church doesn't make sense. That would mean that the pattern that was shown to Moses was the church. That doesn't make much sense at all, to me. God has a literal tabernacle and throne in heaven, which the earthly tabernacle and ark of the covenant were made after, "according to the pattern".

Comment: @jlaverde: If you believe there's a literal throne floating around in the heavens, then there's no point having a conversation with you, because all reason is clearly lost on you.

Comment: @BYE Did you ever chance your vote here?  If so, you can remove your obsolete comments (And if not, you may vote to do so).

Comment: @Flimzy The Bible teaches that God lives in the 3rd heaven. Which is obviously not the clouds that you see when you look up. It is a place where you can taste, see, and hear. It is a physical place where God lives. If you think it isn't real, can you really call yourself a Christian? Christ taught that He is going to prepare a place for us there. I guess Jesus was lying and it's figurative then?

Comment: @jlaverde: The "third heaven" is, obviously (to most people), metaphor. To say that God, a spirit, who created the physical world (and by definition must therefore exist outside of the physical world) lives in a physical place is, to most people, complete insanity. I can turn it around to you: "If you believe God is confined to a physical place, can you call yourself a true Christian?" Fortunately, neither view on this issue has the least to do with the definition of a Christian.

Comment: @Flimzy So because God created something, it automatically means He cannot live in it? That is totally contrary to all of Scripture as we are created and He wishes to dwell within us. The Third Heaven is NOT a metaphor. Paul says it was a physical place, where a man was caught up and is the paradise of God! And that the man HEARD unspeakable things. The same place where Jesus spoke about and said "in my Father's house are many mansions". Once again I ask, so in your mind Jesus was lying? Or are these 'imaginary' mansions? Come on man be honest with yourself for one second and read your Bible.

Comment: @jlaverde: Dude. Whatever. We disagree. I'm 100% sure you're wrong. You're 100% sure I'm wrong.  Me reading the bible won't convince me that your opinion is right any more than you reading the bible will convince you that I'm right.

Comment: But to answer your question: They are (blatantly, obviously, to the vast majority of Christians), metaphorical mansions.

Comment: @Flimzy Do you know what a metaphor is? If you do, tell me what Jesus is referring to 'metaphorically' then. And how is it blatantly obvious? What words from that verse make it so 'blatant'? Or perhaps is your own warped view that makes it blatant? You don't believe that there is a heaven. Or that Jesus has prepared a place for us. I'm assuming you don't believe in a literal Second Coming? How about a literal death of Jesus? Because some people used to think this also. Or a literal Jesus?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27711/discussion-between-flimzy-and-jlaverde).

Comment: I will believe if I see it in the Bible. Could you back up your claims that it is simply a metaphor?